# i18next translation inside map

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have issue with translation inside a map function using react-i18next.

```
import data from '../../projectsData.json';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();

    return (
        <div>
            {data.projects.map((project, index) => {
                return (
                    <Link to='/' key={index}>
                        <img
                            src={project.image}
                            alt={project.title}
                        />
                        <p>{project.title}</p>    //there should be translated text
                    </Link>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

The projectsData.json file looks like that:

```
{
    "projects": [
        {
            "title": "projekt 1",
            "description": "to jest opis projektu 1",
            "id": "111",
            "image": "https://placedog.net/640/480/1"
        },
        {
            "title": "projekt 2",
            "description": "to jest opis projektu 2",
            "id": "222",
            "image": "https://placedog.net/640/480/2"
        },
        {
            "title": "projekt 3",
            "description": "to jest opis projektu 3",
            "id": "333",
            "image": "https://placedog.net/640/480/3"
        },
        {
            "title": "projekt 4",
            "description": "to jest opis projektu 4",
            "id": "444",
            "image": "https://placedog.net/640/480/4"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to add also translation into translation file, but it will be an object with projects titles:

```
{    "projects": {
        "title1": "Project 1",
        "title2": "Project 2",
        "title3": "Project 3",
        "title4": "Project 4"
    }
}
```

So I'm not able to turn it:

```
"title": "projekt 1"
```

into:

```
"title": `${t('projects.title1')}
```

in projectsData.json file, because it's json.
Also I can use useTranslation hook only inside a React component. How can I manage this issue?

Answer (score 0):

For using translation in out of react component you can use `i18next.t`.

```js
import i18next from 'i18next';
i18next.t('your word');
```

Also you don't need to change json file. you can use `t` method for translation into map function

```html
<p>{t(project.title)}</p>
```

Comment: that's right. But in translation file I'm not able to set multiple same keys ('title', inside project object). So I still need to:
option 1: use t() function from i18 in projectsData.json file, which is impossible i guess
or option 2: somehow map project object from translation JSON inside paragraph, but it is inside a map function...
Am I wrong?

Comment: I think you need something like interpolation in i18next and you can check it with this link: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple.

```
t('array', { returnObjects: true });
// -> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Reference: https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/objects-and-arrays